# Magento 2: FedEx Freight setup for packages over 150lbs

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, fedex

We are using FedEx as shipping method and have products which are more then 150lbs. So, according to this, we need to use FedEx Freight (Allowed Methods: Freight). We contacted FedEx support and this method is already allowed/included into our FedEx account. But problem is when we add product with 150lbs weight or more, there are no shipping methods to choose. We got "Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time". Otherwise, if we add to cart product with less then 150lbs everything shows up normally. FedEx shopping methods setup is more/less default one.

[image]

We are using Magento 2.1.16

Does anyone have any clue how to make it (Freight) appear on storefront when we add to cart products with more then 150lbs weight?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the specific method is not allowed in Fedex for above 150lbs, how could Fedex will accept the shipment to be shipped ?

Comment: Hi @AbdulPathan, I already mentioned that this specific method is allowed in Fedex. And that was my concern, why it is still not displayed in Magento?